# SpriteKit Background Scrolling and NodePosition in screen

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

I'm writing a top down racing game, I have a big Main Node that hold all the elements of the level and a joystick that move the car. I want to scroll the viewport of the app when the car reach the angles or the margins of the screen. To do this I will move the position of the mainNode accordingly to the car direction. There's my problem, I need to know when the car reaches the border of the screen, so I need to use the screen coordinate system (480*320) but taking the car.position return me the coordinate relative to the main node (1400*600)... How I can translate the position of my SKSpriteNode car to the screen coordinate system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use a combination of [`[MYSKView convertPoint:MYCGPoint fromScene:MYSKScene];`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKView/convertPoint%3afromScene%3a), [`[MYSKScene convertPointToView: MYCGPoint];`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKScene/convertPointToView%3a), and [`[MYSKNodeA convertPoint: MYCGPoint toNode: MYSKNodeB];`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/convertPoint%3atoNode%3a).